# Create instance dynamically from type (to use in generics)

Tags: generics, reflection, swift

How do I create a class dynamically from an instance?

I have function that uses generics to generate data. So lets say I pass a complex type

> generateData() as [ClassA] //Usage

```
func generateData<T>() ->[T] //Declaration
```

So lets say I have an instance of ClassA or ClassB. How do I generate a list from them during runtime?

```
//doesn't work nor do .class
let classType = instanceOfClassA.dynamicType 
let myGeneratedAInstances = generateData() as [classType]
```

Comment: What is `generateData()` supposed to do? Return an empty array capable of being filled with `ClassA` or `ClassB` or whatever? Then you need to tell it what the class is, not cast it afterwards, which is easy to do, just by passing an instance to `generateData`. Like this, perhaps:

`func generateData<T>(T) -> [T] {
    return Array<T>()
}
`

`let instanceOfClassA = ClassA()`
`let myGeneratedAInstances = generateData(instanceOfClassA)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse an object to an dictionary and also a dictionary back to an object, then try this class: https://github.com/evermeer/EVCloudKitDao/blob/master/AppMessage/AppMessage/CloudKit/EVReflection.swift